# Chrome Extension - Bookmark OnClick Event Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have already googled a lot and I did not find solution for it because there is no OnClick event listener in chrome.bookmarks api.

I want to open bookmarks links in new tab upon click instead of existing tab.  I tried it using Bookmarklet, but in that case, website icons are not visible in Bookmarks Bar, so I thought OnClick event can do the trick but unfortunately it is not there.

Any solution will be helpful!

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Comment: It is already described, but let me explain a bit.  When somebody click on any bookmark link, it should open in new tab and new tab should be set as active tab!

Comment: Well there's no such API as you can see in the documentation.

Comment: I know that but I was looking for some solution because there is always some other way!

Comment: @JohneDoe what's the other way?

Comment: I have one in mind, but problem is icon in bookmark bar

Comment: "there is always some other way" doesn't necessarily mean it's usable or relevant. Sometimes the other way is "don't do it" or "submit a feature request" (on https://crbug.com).